# For loop with shift right until zero, and include zero

Tags: c, for-loop, bit-shift

Is there a more elegant way to do the below for loop. The if statement to check for zero and then break looks ugly, but if I don't include it the code will infinite loop.

```
for (int i = 8; i >= 0; i >>= 1) {
    printf("%d", i);
    if (i == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

The ideal output should be:

```
8
4
2
1
0
```

Even though I said for loop, any loop structure can be used, e.g. while or do-while

Comment: why not a `i=8; do { ...; i >>= 1; } while(i > 0)`?

Comment: Both of you two read the problem statement. He wants the trailing zero loop to run.

Comment: @Joshua: Enlighten me. Why is this UB?

Comment: @Olaf: Turns out I misread something.

Comment: Ah we're back to [code golfing](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com). Here is my take, then: `int i = 8 << 1; while (i) printf("%d", i>>1), i>>=1;` works for me.

Comment: @RadLexus, I'm not generally inclined to attribute elegance to heavily golfed code.  Golfed code is certainly *short*, but that's not all there is to elegance.

Comment: yes, not really looking for code golfing. readability is more important imo.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I meant that to emphasize code golfing is off-topic for SO. However, I stand by the underlying *solution* :), which is moving the stop criterium by a single step. (I see it has been submitted as an answer.)

Comment: Perhaps `for (int i = 8, j = -1; j; i >>= 1) {
        printf("%d", i);
        j = i;
    }`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a more elegant way to do the below for loop. The if statement to check for zero and then break looks ugly, but if I don't include it the code will infinite loop.

If you *do* include it, then it's pointless to provide a loop termination condition in the `for` statement.  Elegance may be somewhat in the eye of the beholder, but since your loop termination condition will always be satisfied, I might instead write the loop like this:

```
for (int i = 8; ; i >>= 1) {
    printf("%d", i);
    if (i == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could restructure it so that the right shift is performed after the termination test, but before the rest of the loop body:

```
for (unsigned int i = 8 << 1; i; ) {
    i >>= 1;
    printf("%u", i);
}
```

Comment: I am hoping there is some trick to keep the logic confined to the for loop, but if the extra if statement is necessary then I can keep it.

Comment: Your alternative is starting to look a little better though.

Comment: I almost wrote that second loop but bailed out after considering the starting case of 2^31.

Comment: @Joshua, if your existing code handles 2^31 then so does my second loop.  More likely, however, your `int`s are 32-bit, so 2^31 is outside their range.  My change to type `unsigned int` was intentional, for exactly this purpose.  If you need more range than `unsigned int` provides then you probably have wider types available.  In the end, of course, yes, you expend one bit on having a starting value larger than anything you intend to print.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: There exists a platform in which unsigned int is no wider than int. Other than that what you say is correct.

Comment: @Joshua, there are many platforms on which `unsigned int` is no wider than `int`, but few, if any, where the former does not have more *precision*.  You're right, though, that the unsigned type may have a padding bit instead of a value bit where the signed type has its sign bit.  Inasmuch as the ranges of integer types are implementation-defined anyway, however, the type that you must choose depends on the implementation in any case.

Answer (score 2):

If you start with the bit number instead of the bit mask, you can write the loop like this

```
for ( int bit=3, mask=1<<bit; bit >= -1; bit--, mask >>= 1 ) {
    printf( "%d\n", mask );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I can do is:

```
for(int i = 8;;) {
    printf("%d", i);
    if (!i) break;
    i >>= 1;
}
```

Some (N + .5) loops can be packed into the condition clause; however this isn't one of them.

Comment: @user3386109: Also I eliminated the pointless loop test (which is the main change).

Comment: @user3386109: And my answer is you can't do that if that 8 is really a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know you always want to print "0" in the end, you could:

```
for (int i = 8; i > 0; i >>= 1) {
  printf("%d", i);
}
printf("0");
```

Alternatively, you could first **left shift"" the starting value, then do:

```
for (int i = 8 << 1; i > 0;) {
  i >>= 1;
  printf("%d", i);
}
```

The downside of this method is that you lose bit width. If the starting value is to big, you'll get an overflow in the left shift.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my not so simple but one line code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 32;
    while(printf("%d\n", i), i >>= 1, !i ? printf("0\n"), 0 : 1);
}
```

I hope it helps! `:)`

Comment: The "printf" in my real life code is actual several lines of code using the loop variable, so please take that into consideration.

Comment: @Noah, so insert some white-spaces(line breaks or so) in between! `:)`

Comment: Any c++ statement (or program) can be made into 1 line just by removing all the '\n' characters, that doesnt make it better, it usually makes it worse.

Comment: @Ben, I know my code is not very clean and I mentioned that in my answer and also the questioner was looking for a compact way to do that. although by adding a simple explanation comment to my code it would be like an inline function! `:)`